# Generic List to Map?

Tags: apex, map, sobject

I have two functions that convert a list of SObjects to a map.
They do the same thing except that the SObject is different.

How can i combine them to one generic function?

```
private Map<String, License_Item__c> LicenseItemListToMap(List<License_Item__c> licenseItems) {
    Map<String, License_Item__c> returnMap = new Map<String, License_Item__c>();
    for(License_Item__c item : licenseItems) {
        returnMap.put(item.Name,item);
    }
    return returnMap;
}

private Map<String, License_Item_Limit__c> LicenseItemLimitListToMap(List<License_Item_Limit__c> licenseItemLimits) {
    Map<String, License_Item_Limit__c> returnMap = new Map<String, License_Item_Limit__c>();
    for(License_Item_Limit__c item : licenseItemLimits) {
        returnMap.put(item.Name,item);
    }
    return returnMap;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the generic sObject:

```
void recordsByFieldToMap(Map<String, sObject> target, SObjectField field, sObject[] source) {
  for(sObject record: source) {
    target.put((String)record.get(field), record);
  }
}
```

It would be used like this:

```
Map<String, License_Item__c> items = new Map<String, License_Item__c>();
recordsByFieldToMap(items, License_Item__c.Name, records);
```

We take advantage of the fact that we can pass objects by reference (items) to cause changes, and the dynamic `sObject.get` method lets us extract the field values without fuss. There are other ways to do this as well, but this is the approach I would take.

Comment: What if i don't want to pass objects by reference, and i want to return a map?